# Memory usage increases dramatically

Tags: python, memory, overhead

I have a problem with memory usage of my code and it is that the memory increase dramatically, 3 GB per hour and I need around 80 hours for my calculation. How can I check memory usage for each part of my calculation?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I suggest to take a look around and see how to ask a proper question, to increase the chances to gave some good answers from the community: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/tour. For example, could you please show your efforts and paste a snippet of your code?

Comment: @Cabrra Thanks! I don't know how to pick parts of the code to reproduce the probelem. Can I just put that part with defined arrays?

Comment: You can insert `gc.collect()` in places where you think it would be beneficial. Of course, if you are holding references to memory it will not be freed. Also, if you are allocating memory in `C`, then you are responsible for freeing it.

Comment: @John Anderson This looks like the *answer* rather than a mere *comment*. Would you mind making an answer out of it?

Comment: @JohnAnderson Should I put `gc.collect()` at each `static` block I have?

Comment: Python is a powerful language to manage large datasets (data mining etc). I don't understand fully the problem, therefore I am not the proper person to give you a correct answer. However, did you consider using other ways to handle the data setting up? Maybe an array is too basic and takes way too much space in memory. You could build a map from a file/storage and track the data that way. Again, I am not in that field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can insert `gc.collect()` in places where you think it would be beneficial. Of course, if you are holding references to memory it will not be freed. Also, if you are allocating memory in C, then you are responsible for freeing it.

The normal memory handling facilities of `Python` do a very good job, so I would only recommend calling `gc.collect()` if you are sure you are deleting references to large amounts of memory and it is not getting released fast enough.

As to where you should put these calls, there is no hard fast rule, just keep in mind that only unreferenced memory will be freed.